# Git archive file encoded

Tags: git, archive

I am new to `GIT`. I have been handed a `GIT` archive and it files like this

> \test\test.git\objects\00\5fb6e929e2762eed7e8345d06945d5d8141849
>   \test\test.git\objects\01\494219e9c92d383153eb92de0283faa9692ce7
>   \test\test.git\objects\02\421362044b26f76d190260f4249111fc9d6e46
>   \test\test.git\objects\02\85a00a16a2ba90ac9b17c5bb87f4ce4cd3c8c8
>   \test\test.git\objects\02\f85772df5f042045c82332bb7e0d32399cf1e3
>   \test\test.git\objects\03\b781b1923de696a496e442ea64c913a4894bac
>   \test\test.git\objects\03\bf39d1e9ab52b4c04bee33d58963df49efec0e
>   \test\test.git\objects\05\0b896afd638e1cc039ff5f53d6f65f5ab4107d
>   \test\test.git\objects\05\ca8244a9d180436f6fbcb74551c599616f9cfd
>   \test\test.git\objects\05\ebe3180ae0d916fe1b3a5667267199804b0690
>   \test\test.git\objects\07\99f41459016188054f1b8191ed2ef27e6ce1a7
>   \test\test.git\objects\08\246e8f6040e57c0d0692af62bf3435e0972cf7
>   \test\test.git\objects\08\f71098c8ba55d46e18deef05ea61610307c836
>   \test\test.git\objects\09\425ffaec3fcb979b80c18c8c5fa758f692a828
>   \test\test.git\objects\0a\9e78cc8721753cad6d0148a79505d7d7aed34c
>   \test\test.git\objects\0b\4301aec09ef82f7476006065be2378f408c95a
>   \test\test.git\objects\0b\fdfde72a39d3d93f392dd1dfb6166e42548ffd
>   \test\test.git\objects\0e\962e544079109b65561fd639eefa74c5265d58
>   \test\test.git\objects\0e\ade11145d78800cdaa45220c157794fc0943dd
>   \test\test.git\objects\0f\7101ea0d887908301181e9f7225d83af74d935
>   \test\test.git\objects\10\42a736b20dc22d81432d4b65718066c21dc87d
>   \test\test.git\objects\10\679ea864f4ecd3a7e20348cbd5dbcf32be1872
>   \test\test.git\objects\11\80b4c5ddddeb62824bf57664da85b40372f8ec
>   \test\test.git\objects\12\3fcc15564fd1dd4b826775999c80b2561ec221
>   \test\test.git\objects\12\4933a6cf43fb094376ad43ec3d359e428e24c2
>   \test\test.git\objects\13\c48d8f7289de624c6007261670fe2eebdfc24a
>   \test\test.git\objects\13\d574ecab451b0b3a258a56d97bc33cd72172f8
>   \test\test.git\objects\14\1fef448f81b33e94e1163b7577a00133fa0ee9
>   \test\test.git\objects\14\c17d37af1b81d6e0fb375da0805a185c842a37
>   \test\test.git\objects\15\1bc42a050c43eb246427570eb9ca511c9fb787
>   \test\test.git\objects\15\1d1d1c7d9312ce1ff8e66b74782b05223e95d4
>   \test\test.git\objects\15\549fa06a2293580c995bc5935a422adaaf93d2
>   \test\test.git\objects\16\99c21165deecb5cfdcc16d984627daae4ad0d6

How can I convert this archive into actual source code??

**Edit:**

Entire list:

```
\test\readme.txt
\test\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
\test\.git\config
\test\.git\description
\test\.git\HEAD
\test\.git\index
\test\.git\hooks\applypatch-msg.sample
\test\.git\hooks\commit-msg.sample
\test\.git\hooks\post-update.sample
\test\.git\hooks\pre-applypatch.sample
\test\.git\hooks\pre-commit.sample
\test\.git\hooks\pre-push.sample
\test\.git\hooks\pre-rebase.sample
\test\.git\hooks\prepare-commit-msg.sample
\test\.git\hooks\update.sample
\test\.git\info\exclude
\test\.git\logs\HEAD
\test\.git\logs\refs\heads\master
\test\.git\logs\refs\remotes\origin\master
\test\.git\objects\10\c0895cf93a1f13a465179a2a5f643ada979cdf
\test\.git\objects\91\2f93d9c510f64734a20d6db4e7bbe8225dff10
\test\.git\objects\bc\b97791a519b2bae4153c233db171973d0bf5c3
\test\.git\refs\heads\master
\test\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master
\test\test.git\config
\test\test.git\description
\test\test.git\gitk.cache
\test\test.git\HEAD
\test\test.git\hooks\applypatch-msg.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\commit-msg.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\post-commit.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\post-receive.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\post-update.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\pre-applypatch.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\pre-commit.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\pre-rebase.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\prepare-commit-msg.sample
\test\test.git\hooks\update.sample
\test\test.git\info\exclude
\test\test.git\objects\00\5fb6e929e2762eed7e8345d06945d5d8141849
\test\test.git\objects\01\494219e9c92d383153eb92de0283faa9692ce7
\test\test.git\objects\02\421362044b26f76d190260f4249111fc9d6e46
\test\test.git\objects\02\85a00a16a2ba90ac9b17c5bb87f4ce4cd3c8c8
\test\test.git\objects\02\f85772df5f042045c82332bb7e0d32399cf1e3
\test\test.git\objects\03\b781b1923de696a496e442ea64c913a4894bac
\test\test.git\objects\03\bf39d1e9ab52b4c04bee33d58963df49efec0e
\test\test.git\objects\05\0b896afd638e1cc039ff5f53d6f65f5ab4107d
\test\test.git\objects\05\ca8244a9d180436f6fbcb74551c599616f9cfd
\test\test.git\objects\05\ebe3180ae0d916fe1b3a5667267199804b0690
\test\test.git\objects\07\99f41459016188054f1b8191ed2ef27e6ce1a7
\test\test.git\objects\08\246e8f6040e57c0d0692af62bf3435e0972cf7
\test\test.git\objects\08\f71098c8ba55d46e18deef05ea61610307c836
\test\test.git\objects\09\425ffaec3fcb979b80c18c8c5fa758f692a828
\test\test.git\objects\0a\9e78cc8721753cad6d0148a79505d7d7aed34c
\test\test.git\objects\0b\4301aec09ef82f7476006065be2378f408c95a
\test\test.git\objects\0b\fdfde72a39d3d93f392dd1dfb6166e42548ffd
\test\test.git\objects\0e\962e544079109b65561fd639eefa74c5265d58
\test\test.git\objects\0e\ade11145d78800cdaa45220c157794fc0943dd
\test\test.git\objects\0f\7101ea0d887908301181e9f7225d83af74d935
\test\test.git\objects\10\42a736b20dc22d81432d4b65718066c21dc87d
\test\test.git\objects\10\679ea864f4ecd3a7e20348cbd5dbcf32be1872
\test\test.git\objects\11\80b4c5ddddeb62824bf57664da85b40372f8ec
\test\test.git\objects\12\3fcc15564fd1dd4b826775999c80b2561ec221
\test\test.git\objects\12\4933a6cf43fb094376ad43ec3d359e428e24c2
\test\test.git\objects\13\c48d8f7289de624c6007261670fe2eebdfc24a
\test\test.git\objects\13\d574ecab451b0b3a258a56d97bc33cd72172f8
\test\test.git\objects\14\1fef448f81b33e94e1163b7577a00133fa0ee9
\test\test.git\objects\14\c17d37af1b81d6e0fb375da0805a185c842a37
\test\test.git\objects\15\1bc42a050c43eb246427570eb9ca511c9fb787
\test\test.git\objects\15\1d1d1c7d9312ce1ff8e66b74782b05223e95d4
\test\test.git\objects\15\549fa06a2293580c995bc5935a422adaaf93d2
\test\test.git\objects\16\99c21165deecb5cfdcc16d984627daae4ad0d6
\test\test.git\objects\17\a0ce9f0309f62b46c46555d64cfcacfc7a5894
\test\test.git\objects\17\b3880c81057de0a77f4eba0979a68209fe1156
\test\test.git\objects\19\f36508af693f76369e088ef23fddb013c1e867
\test\test.git\objects\1a\b21ed65f364c7eba84c0b3b973215d79eb4237
\test\test.git\objects\1d\23d3b5e0edb36652edb125e177e83570b9d0de
\test\test.git\objects\1d\d8c28aa9ad4f83d634491572bcc2aa0a6e66f6
\test\test.git\objects\1f\81fe04a6365cdb21b49341bc5006437913655a
\test\test.git\objects\20\73cdb02ce86feed01a432db741f29314df6929
\test\test.git\objects\20\90a576efe0ea104ef64b90139ee75ecfa4bae6
\test\test.git\objects\21\bedc8f6a2a958fc4e33c6314b14b7d7c11e5ac
\test\test.git\objects\23\46767ea6eeebd8f766dbb2fd11d4890960a9c1
\test\test.git\objects\24\727a63192f74ba597e0708cd390012ce32319c
\test\test.git\objects\24\79db58d2d007d74fa528392bb5febb90609b32
\test\test.git\objects\25\16f006321aad96bb2b2c808e12d6a98ad932c0
\test\test.git\objects\25\98c2e8ff631c443fb7521933b9db984ba15dea
\test\test.git\objects\27\11131413d5117402df90c7ad282484aa0e50fd
\test\test.git\objects\27\3d4340b5a99b72866b1e860ff6b71e351dcdde
\test\test.git\objects\28\b203afb090b42830008bdc5af90ffe41adb510
\test\test.git\objects\28\ed95ccf047b5bf64900f76245d96cc0b16c0be
\test\test.git\objects\28\eeba6a9bf436d8d7a44e836418d26c2a4d7178
\test\test.git\objects\29\5af91775ebccb96753d5bebbebe0e042768234
\test\test.git\objects\29\a5e50e4e72326b00da6da581b2dd5dcda91d83
\test\test.git\objects\29\dd4b2b0539542b7f76dd577c9c9120a3d35b9b
\test\test.git\objects\2a\5c68ae1a21cec9a44c55eb1df3be516c3b2612
\test\test.git\objects\2a\faa739fd5a6ed94a3b7cfbcfa79b9712b0dc11
\test\test.git\objects\2b\7e6836110d5a9ee48aab6a3c4ec3f65943e3a1
\test\test.git\objects\2c\49884589d898341157ce0077ae92fc1ba4b4ac
\test\test.git\objects\2d\0fe89176188917c60803a64c674e4fb8211075
\test\test.git\objects\2e\0ae271d918d04288ffb8596aa7a18c0a0167a5
\test\test.git\objects\2f\6fb8b050d8472d26fc4d234baae594628e5cee
\test\test.git\objects\2f\be66bdfcb019445fc2a3450ff1ef99e14a3a63
\test\test.git\objects\31\b83b58253e28374e13325793133657a38a6bb8
\test\test.git\objects\32\665e03ba3ef1a49b5e0396b32e516660d6fb6c
\test\test.git\objects\33\842e69ad25cb8ebab1c7aba608add96f8cb1be
\test\test.git\objects\33\99ed638baf0d26847b4daefa84fd4b14571dd7
\test\test.git\objects\34\2ab5a650dc2276d7bdef1f1a49094ac53db9ad
\test\test.git\objects\37\7fa8d93e51fef34e0e14530c09479665dfc30c
\test\test.git\objects\37\93452b5aca3e343f883649d4302fdc9141ec2a
\test\test.git\objects\38\0d616718def1d899b516d155db79479f5c7b17
\test\test.git\objects\38\646fd6b60ea5f680a7c00c74c47e063f12419b
\test\test.git\objects\3a\2a34a7c9739f0b23576eb8b6bf14fc83cdafba
\test\test.git\objects\3c\37a6a528b746ae1fa0a4ef4b287f7ca97d3f88
\test\test.git\objects\3c\a68e87fa94d2d65259d4453ca5432935ea0d70
\test\test.git\objects\3d\8128ce28b443a36740fe80b856695703fb4188
\test\test.git\objects\3f\421615e3de1758e051b095f0fdce3698f8e39d
\test\test.git\objects\40\ec68999f7dce6951872bcd1b2c55394283f13c
\test\test.git\objects\41\36bbc6572f8c48d482f76e0c4e59ef8b56bbc6
\test\test.git\objects\43\b72fa179e9fea170dc54eb05964f147d4ebc5c
\test\test.git\objects\43\f8b5a9b0c1725f9c4d3be28ab3a0418084a927
\test\test.git\objects\45\018b67276c8d292f810620e1b5cb984c97d598
\test\test.git\objects\45\7a874f142b59b96f0db75d1bf5b34b65a99824
\test\test.git\objects\45\c43c3fac60c65114e6a078ff9a950ce1f29eaa
\test\test.git\objects\46\e9fb2501c954cff5045ac6a952504d22e1a419
\test\test.git\objects\47\145041bd37b6746a420eef6500ec7706a83cb6
\test\test.git\objects\47\1b7cce284a53d52b082d665b10cc58221e519a
\test\test.git\objects\47\6c5afcde492cf8a96438dd047365d05931c13d
\test\test.git\objects\47\c4f4a55e06b24d228875e826eed56ee2fa0a00
\test\test.git\objects\48\21e7c2d34c51e8ab54c1da94ad648dd1ff280d
\test\test.git\objects\49\a0116b2ac697be12898330e7afb75a9f3d5a3c
\test\test.git\objects\4a\766361e29e6117f2578c49eabd17d405638a63
\test\test.git\objects\4a\e0fc96bcbc1b3411138712320c4016592233cb
\test\test.git\objects\4b\c49003e02d22e8bfe89e50736ab3a32addd7da
\test\test.git\objects\4c\184142047bd2b24dd9a90ec3a6e7347e978b36
\test\test.git\objects\4d\a3812895d5ab88bb4d43fb26291f3654105f94
\test\test.git\objects\4e\01d2ce75064ff23a300af42df3aff7151ded6f
\test\test.git\objects\4e\5c0ee41811beb4fa80afca82a1b1f4547dbdcd
\test\test.git\objects\4f\33a8ebd75c8ecee42164221b82a56906ee4a12
\test\test.git\objects\4f\56b4d622681a6cd406e8966039d07f8accbdf1
\test\test.git\objects\50\9b07a0f8ea483841ff4d82aab16ff17b12ec28
\test\test.git\objects\50\a9f6f64d78ed4c6f8b6b2f6384e8bf2c5a0d78
\test\test.git\objects\51\51c917d09c55ac78128985515b6cf855cafbc8
\test\test.git\objects\52\b5d1dcad4c9cff23d545c029ffbef7b4e22961
\test\test.git\objects\55\5b929721f7a576f9a7e70026a7248bfe916869
\test\test.git\objects\57\1d6ca4f2791c70eb0803cf326f4723e7038537
\test\test.git\objects\5b\08b8dbd877d23cfd5c5ec7f4c047da78d76ef9
\test\test.git\objects\5c\49e2b56ee562665fe9533a362dd5fd88009c18
\test\test.git\objects\5d\3ce162b5fee86b4c7e825b38118ff0387c6b79
\test\test.git\objects\5f\0f800e8e49484daeb77e76ecbde2b7dd5e3afc
\test\test.git\objects\5f\60ed506d7f1a7e8684114309adc53d690e8f65
\test\test.git\objects\60\70e3debd5bc450f736a756bd4a71ab33958b9e
\test\test.git\objects\61\cc25e719585a0d570ac74095732d1226b2a78d
\test\test.git\objects\61\da0a10ff2ada8a6dc8bed534535fc36f8879ca
\test\test.git\objects\62\b1b462f3967b2f53278d4021c717b202684dba
\test\test.git\objects\63\d9ba85215a03ca5f8817f428b8161fdf8be86c
\test\test.git\objects\64\328b34176ac3c5acc399396cf1868ff80398e3
\test\test.git\objects\64\57217b989ef71bb559b85fdb76ff73e2987f82
\test\test.git\objects\64\9d410e18243bf047920a82b11ae501e4bcb02a
\test\test.git\objects\66\27b36e6e540d38eadbbe30f2c581081f2e3325
\test\test.git\objects\66\39fc3c88825369d285fb7acb46b07bb8d562e2
\test\test.git\objects\66\46601c8d4df7dd4bcacba0486be1dca804cc5e
\test\test.git\objects\67\131137a7e280e925024a642918bdbf4d6db358
\test\test.git\objects\68\0936ed62adcf4d41145a07f15360cb294d10c4
\test\test.git\objects\69\00b176c99f65471b4ac1164c16b443382c426f
\test\test.git\objects\6a\8c9915b4f8231829ca1a1c6f667d4017b1a1cc
\test\test.git\objects\6a\f072df7d8878100b54da16dba8a14b2bdcd04e
\test\test.git\objects\6b\087318c668f6c68c0d97ae41427d171a39f7b7
\test\test.git\objects\6c\a6420add8e387fe5805d0f2706e7b645f34da8
\test\test.git\objects\6c\d5e6efa00f7f3e84d28f0e47845688e45259b1
\test\test.git\objects\6e\15624bc349718c27a72d419c6bcd07d248b8c6
\test\test.git\objects\6f\0daf0c75c4ff279f48c60135d35b5ff9cddf35
\test\test.git\objects\70\72a81895882d5aebe50e384e97a34611965995
\test\test.git\objects\71\4e454095b1a83b1786963098355911a843a0f7
\test\test.git\objects\72\17a8ce27c9cd9b29524ffe79eaec214fd65c66
\test\test.git\objects\72\61d92fc3f5728cf460f85aefbee181f6a16ea4
\test\test.git\objects\73\3a3b242d1fe0bd550965d45c0147d9887cc9f9
\test\test.git\objects\75\2c0af49b9cc50e921785ac02c6d74f70152409
\test\test.git\objects\76\30db74ab8594565c4df1453e473c3d7006a430
\test\test.git\objects\76\3a96a289830a3738c9541555d16f6794029663
\test\test.git\objects\77\7f4407272c96b648975fe6804c5f19749b1aee
\test\test.git\objects\78\818ac7c9623577c5132b9bd5bd7a09a18e5753
\test\test.git\objects\7a\0abfaf9cb209874b47269e93e160996f689f8c
\test\test.git\objects\7a\a1f34838cbc64bff00ff25d880c2bb52c0cb06
\test\test.git\objects\7a\c11abe564b8fc095745c8d4192e037f3a60dfd
\test\test.git\objects\7a\f704febf8e7076894471f6b3bdea9ff0e1a827
\test\test.git\objects\7b\9409fa26014f0d3c9318a33fd51754e396aad6
\test\test.git\objects\7d\0a1d051cd3eaef1a3aef4e2425ff90e79f62f3
\test\test.git\objects\7e\347dfab5d71a692460399423c36a855a41540c
\test\test.git\objects\7e\e8e51ba0cf4e58994b1c635424ee3d45a3b2f0
\test\test.git\objects\81\16475b31458b102a4e169e1b8fe6e178ad4ef9
\test\test.git\objects\83\96d3bbd60a64b8d6d772c024b2cfedf88ca4ad
\test\test.git\objects\83\a81f922e211efd134d25f4f93c1b89b7cefa34
\test\test.git\objects\85\f363f0e9b589b07a62ac9140957a7414c3497b
\test\test.git\objects\86\0549fe2f58455889a0a42315a027f7864e9b8e
\test\test.git\objects\86\57637c798a052411f45571bf001e2dfe3026d8
\test\test.git\objects\86\d7a7960306d7c17650152db7605f1b0c94c66f
\test\test.git\objects\88\58a730f5b82fbaf35f0c6b4c7dad65cf068acf
\test\test.git\objects\88\d4ad47c8ded72cc70433401cd1db6695916566
\test\test.git\objects\89\16be0be552b00e1582eb11bf2260ae3a829e2c
\test\test.git\objects\8c\1ecf77eef1a3fd361cf6103e498fc468a9c6f4
\test\test.git\objects\8c\40c9f2d70f0b544a705fda73c93ddb88c4f6eb
\test\test.git\objects\8c\f87f3fcb19b7f508bd116b0d5f05d5a798fe6b
\test\test.git\objects\8d\47ef6abb386db1a84a1fcc65248cea0b7142f2
\test\test.git\objects\8d\63c6d5433d4c81f3225c1d0254923f1a1b6651
\test\test.git\objects\8d\8ed26c6b12efba1c74a9b1d0b41d42119cb8e0
\test\test.git\objects\8d\b10787e929e3189e298708b522e10289580a81
\test\test.git\objects\8d\e2bdd8e687a0919402d81086de881fae5d339a
\test\test.git\objects\8e\c837865002543bf46826b6ba2c0f622941a7b1
\test\test.git\objects\8f\571eab34b27130ce642cfc5fe78b1cc8e21f3a
\test\test.git\objects\8f\6bc95d9b20e6ffe1723f5cf2c3f6a6f8bc2569
\test\test.git\objects\90\078d4f183ee441879aeed62c792fcf6ffb4f1e
\test\test.git\objects\90\3a1f9e8a9844612e74a8f3c2eefa53d4fa870d
\test\test.git\objects\90\aab21d01eb2626918800f4f3e705ecce85bfca
\test\test.git\objects\90\fcc307b4627f73856ec95847c23e731400f0e7
\test\test.git\objects\91\df5cb39a58743685be9cd5a6ed944b9b890738
\test\test.git\objects\92\1f88d6956114ddb472b3c43dfcdd3df5be1eb3
\test\test.git\objects\92\c462d97d76f6a14a66c6b0a60cb90991f185ab
\test\test.git\objects\93\3b3896d21866074be99cf4edafa3385a71e3c0
\test\test.git\objects\93\b3dd99833549aefe10e1e5c68f24bd3bb9af76
\test\test.git\objects\93\d8e9b82df7f509057850eb5b19e3bbe30d4909
\test\test.git\objects\94\1ed6dcd98054ddc2d474b9a47ca8b0b1e4b6b0
\test\test.git\objects\95\1d333ea1da53c213b594824136e3c9fe5e0fde
\test\test.git\objects\97\2ab64599c20f778c93b1d254c9446760740744
\test\test.git\objects\97\81d50a15d09ef06bf795865fe0719ab764a86f
\test\test.git\objects\97\82ca6ccc3b066176d7033db17eeddd47d09d9a
\test\test.git\objects\97\a3e95df06596a132bf159b36229950def33a53
\test\test.git\objects\98\05ceab11f1c3a5626398dfb4be605116c588f5
\test\test.git\objects\98\2b230420bf67ec0986b832ada66f163aecee18
\test\test.git\objects\9a\16e3a1ab9d5952bdeeaaf1e787012c1ec92bcc
\test\test.git\objects\9a\94bf35872992db5d30917e74e568340926eb86
\test\test.git\objects\9a\cf5cff87528d7d0d1f769134ead439a2334a88
\test\test.git\objects\9b\055dc2438195a9e9aff03279eb6b467dd869fc
\test\test.git\objects\9b\868c717ab7714fda24b7c937626602c550dc2e
\test\test.git\objects\9d\8d26f8dce09f2ab904e35bec64b99dd316b2d6
\test\test.git\objects\9e\f6affa90e448dbd975cfedb07b770abde9bfc6
\test\test.git\objects\9f\11ba93e9525f13f2e8de3c064a17f511ddf0fc
\test\test.git\objects\9f\160eb40225ef16d4edcd1cbd7ae66112311e72
\test\test.git\objects\9f\6ea75c0935d6b5f61dfa3167a6907b681ab8ad
\test\test.git\objects\9f\ea4de4cbc12638be6cb74fbdd9d02f8a60a05e
\test\test.git\objects\a0\bc7e4f7bcc16f975e72a3e6b4d9eb16a2f1a93
\test\test.git\objects\a1\ad55aec445cafb4fd5e6abae4cafcbfe4d2b7b
\test\test.git\objects\a1\d9b0f113d7c7dda2decaaf39c105e39b4a297b
\test\test.git\objects\a2\18a06b96fcacd988822d0dc0dce44ae0039aae
\test\test.git\objects\a3\fd218c0df29c35898d0045b48f920d2fdaec3d
\test\test.git\objects\a5\3bce9dc9448013189e5c6612663fcb50fded5f
\test\test.git\objects\a5\9bc3cb3ed21fa401d9e26d785a005a83740e5d
\test\test.git\objects\a6\025e5cc55b1b5dc4420561b9ace34024182d57
\test\test.git\objects\a6\1916c88b5e317249fff7d9f94472102e600fad
\test\test.git\objects\a8\37074551f63024a09df04fa15fc85a3ffd9cb8
\test\test.git\objects\a8\4db81ad1fba8da9f622e241069cf61c72a7101
\test\test.git\objects\a8\5b296c562eb368337412318df47ed7ad86c4ea
\test\test.git\objects\a8\d7f929822b3785fe1581f4b97574a1bf5ad570
\test\test.git\objects\a9\52a6dfc1a68cdb3a63a9d3a6d802e544557c98
\test\test.git\objects\a9\715d44fb843f14e802c2e27da30e6e6c741e9a
\test\test.git\objects\a9\c4ba96d4d03ac72cba325011ecc0947d9c0a55
\test\test.git\objects\aa\ca05d438b16e03bd75ba390cccc4a184d9f650
\test\test.git\objects\ac\9dc63597cf649ddc7724aa08c831adb23394f8
\test\test.git\objects\ac\bb2d147848362de40290b58e9065b321010583
\test\test.git\objects\af\3f0e0cbc3a3c40b6818c7e024c10d2ef4429f2
\test\test.git\objects\af\e4f84ae9d7ef0a86ef1a7c832a35680577ee1d
\test\test.git\objects\b0\1c95508ef5eb986e053f4a75a37d085afc6ce3
\test\test.git\objects\b0\e28dd935cd5438f38af0b34b775319fbeb8baa
\test\test.git\objects\b1\60d4ebbe0c2dcb15f08135827cf4cb1bf11d10
\test\test.git\objects\b1\d5c863da4651851dd8a780ba657f3479049e69
\test\test.git\objects\b2\36e45580be27a0198a7dd409548e0e520b1a40
\test\test.git\objects\b2\4afcf273aae5b826814668d76fa510eac8ab8c
\test\test.git\objects\b2\515a560132b53638e49d04da87756ef1a96d63
\test\test.git\objects\b5\3996aaee9caec0f97800e4c4029215f6defdd1
\test\test.git\objects\b5\5501523898858c234153b21ab468986c92912c
\test\test.git\objects\b5\ae5bcc9c43a8bdd21956dcd216b1059d7747fa
\test\test.git\objects\b6\201f8228685e945f735781aac6bee9720be76d
\test\test.git\objects\b6\d2f07a352565e1961d8b249e4a0cb62b84c383
\test\test.git\objects\b7\a45340075a398a5380c3439acfce01daa7d8c2
\test\test.git\objects\b8\a50814a7b72fc79b0c57245b4cbc54b26481e6
\test\test.git\objects\b9\86c3b727170ebd1302e22360b590c51945aa2f
\test\test.git\objects\b9\ef984aa090c4427c82da050e0e06e99dbfc8e7
\test\test.git\objects\bb\13e5682c5760305dc49c31491f4ca9a56cc7c8
\test\test.git\objects\bb\9c9a640588eea48a16438cc40b199756652a7b
\test\test.git\objects\bb\bdd141004f45ca53a695d58bbd8a77feba245e
\test\test.git\objects\bc\57eaeab5847253d7e03ffc57b0a285f8b4be64
\test\test.git\objects\bd\fe9a72c287c9878a5fc420b7a1c81155517a52
\test\test.git\objects\be\155d53c9398b16c77139428da71ce6d9bde573
\test\test.git\objects\be\4b64ea382cc6656cc0f3a15a186974044ad18b
\test\test.git\objects\be\f6f587bba52df6cfbebb658b7b569a8b0b53bc
\test\test.git\objects\bf\621ee2af36dcf7e6acdcc173adffb8ca2adc65
\test\test.git\objects\c0\9cb0df57d09289f7259b0b5b9da25f61ca4d6c
\test\test.git\objects\c0\e97057879ed4473c29b7da956de456779af40e
\test\test.git\objects\c1\2b586f98743180154c078692488beaedc7afa1
\test\test.git\objects\c1\6d07c8c540b31e51e9f801d055b24dabf51665
\test\test.git\objects\c3\3c151a998b595acc94762fc6104e989c5bec98
\test\test.git\objects\c3\de7ef6e1176cd37172513bc59a3613c2e0b89b
\test\test.git\objects\c5\d56ec5d31fcb9ef2c51f7cb6ed0c248dc1c64f
\test\test.git\objects\c6\0743274bb1b09357282108c4d16d59b1e37b84
\test\test.git\objects\c6\0d73282bdbf1d1fc60623aaebde70cfc83d96b
\test\test.git\objects\c6\3ceb0fa6bb8de036a2e9bee98aefc4e5ac3c04
\test\test.git\objects\c8\6250c89639986b810d437f09c7b3470e769cc2
\test\test.git\objects\c9\1c627338419ca47b8ee62c04e97d684c8b0953
\test\test.git\objects\c9\27f490b2c5e3e45dccdbd566fcdd097f641e7c
\test\test.git\objects\c9\49d007fb62536116682a26af0e6a91a85dbe0b
\test\test.git\objects\c9\68195c142ff35bf0ad0a274f64f618bd4e2cae
\test\test.git\objects\c9\a0e0adf8b3f2056bfa9565c40d3c3b83dc9173
\test\test.git\objects\c9\bc56416d826acdd1f8fbe4848b605e128333f9
\test\test.git\objects\cb\bfccac38ce82fa3e397b734deaa960afa6b036
\test\test.git\objects\cd\4427bd12a65f25c4de8affa4d91c0d3b8ed260
\test\test.git\objects\cd\54bec8d11d32274d4ba21c9562867656b3d9bf
\test\test.git\objects\ce\1d61b48a02828b6802a47a2b6d7b863c5ef461
\test\test.git\objects\ce\dccd686fbc961c17fc04e9657741e4d1b47acb
\test\test.git\objects\cf\30d6a7f7eb24923ef78aca5a20f6786793878d
\test\test.git\objects\d0\e2b7c8485b7209281ee5e2908c9c0b63addd6e
\test\test.git\objects\d1\0255c4351eed897ed0ea9d90293faa804a304f
\test\test.git\objects\d2\d6e6bfc676d1feaa9feafe4e14a2c4aa88bc25
\test\test.git\objects\d4\0cb1781d48bc6ee17d936ce3c4ac94a3f8013c
\test\test.git\objects\d4\8365c12d2a575e421e3bdf4bd120efc21537dc
\test\test.git\objects\d4\cde98d9df21201d97de683d79ad039ddc88d61
\test\test.git\objects\d5\8fb46b82cf393830115990060171a86a357788
\test\test.git\objects\d5\93925a105727f2f3ab194c16c3c584d9fa042a
\test\test.git\objects\d6\7c90b0d293d5cb347c9fd8e6c57e982f67bebb
\test\test.git\objects\d6\e41d06009eeadb7f4c87eb8a4e0a2e6454a730
\test\test.git\objects\d7\8b22cc7ec1b45b7574e82f7fba2680d6bff869
\test\test.git\objects\d7\cd0b96a50b3c52e41e012b2238d40e1cfdfe2e
\test\test.git\objects\d8\3118ecf81ad793797c0df7075998c28a2d3f55
\test\test.git\objects\d8\a64560930a95c68de66ac0ba9a5cd87853947c
\test\test.git\objects\da\6e0ca6c4c9acb61c2c66e5b2a05eb9ed3dd1e7
\test\test.git\objects\dc\1cde9175925736a69d5639895389159bc73f12
\test\test.git\objects\dd\7268278ca32a3630e860477e4140ab881be88e
\test\test.git\objects\de\e0a6c68cfdfd7f001875c4eca362ee6adfc852
\test\test.git\objects\df\472b84ad966429d2227d45e71ce94e64c4b1d2
\test\test.git\objects\df\4a29ae3b9114e579d9209bd2c52c4844b3b17e
\test\test.git\objects\df\63294a58234ec1994ac22631134b0fd6ed621f
\test\test.git\objects\e1\fc32bf4a5017e008169feca14c6de87baedbd0
\test\test.git\objects\e3\b4e33e6c85d3ed8b7bee199246f29ae051872a
\test\test.git\objects\e3\cdd447976423d6c6a1fbcb4100d8ee2320ad06
\test\test.git\objects\e4\6ef16a10951a5a9a2f08752916a2c96bedb373
\test\test.git\objects\e5\324b0f9ff701777d8ad0cceb357c5b590fa082
\test\test.git\objects\e5\5a0c4b4741e12c160ed535812f585875d515bb
\test\test.git\objects\e7\154a9f7a3334dfd000b3d06b0cb6c0b9da4942
\test\test.git\objects\e7\21dbd4fa480f81131756093f8c78d2b243d098
\test\test.git\objects\e8\4705c936229cfeb83da5fbc00c5f726a69099e
\test\test.git\objects\e8\6a57bb081ef19d9482b454483efc10b0ab8476
\test\test.git\objects\e8\b539f58e0e3f797dbaa396893f2c8c4f7d64c6
\test\test.git\objects\e9\3669afa9dc61ec4f73222ce1b977e90ba38f32
\test\test.git\objects\ea\6253e1cf8f31904beb7da0793982988b208854
\test\test.git\objects\ec\6bebcc0b27e2277123b1cadf2531579cc9609d
\test\test.git\objects\ee\2fcab8b004b98df5db01c26b10217e6c014213
\test\test.git\objects\ee\6b2e0df5765225656d5a6e044c900e263979d5
\test\test.git\objects\ee\f4791e79fb1e0a1e40f4e602da28410f8dd2d0
\test\test.git\objects\ef\599fcd76794591ed4248d40ed706e952fc8240
\test\test.git\objects\f0\77e7d51d7dc2dad08f177192157b762d07943a
\test\test.git\objects\f1\4fee2fe07f08093f55c10082d8f87f5ea64a0e
\test\test.git\objects\f1\d6f1a2a8d091e5e66f592b748621baac26045e
\test\test.git\objects\f2\869b697e1d1e4dbace309241b8964044464925
\test\test.git\objects\f2\9cb53250ff139d73bfb099e952f9e228c8c29e
\test\test.git\objects\f3\21c405366f394d055fd771434bdfe68d9de3c9
\test\test.git\objects\f3\3b883dbe1955f82ff55414f99f97797644ba73
\test\test.git\objects\f3\85486411c6d96c055a514c57dbd2d2e5002a60
\test\test.git\objects\f3\92da1230fb5d4f82f44475c38eef1be165564b
\test\test.git\objects\f4\4b874eee2954aff07eaf42f79d9241a53f77e9
\test\test.git\objects\f4\f1526b4ee061cd5806fdba2e52187df4057296
\test\test.git\objects\f6\0d1d481e73c278bc6e0161d082b19b26ee72fe
\test\test.git\objects\f7\f5992e4e13df996b5e387f71206e75cceb79b2
\test\test.git\objects\f8\b642fbf4279aedafaef8df39b98e73ef544b99
\test\test.git\objects\fa\c5d83b1c1c79d7e36915b1a12a333bd72eca44
\test\test.git\objects\fb\5b2a2da18cfc6d442b34d2abd9c10311fa2fe1
\test\test.git\objects\fb\eeb4b2d42a1b1cf04a8a9ab09aa664be68262a
\test\test.git\objects\fc\e6c7befd0c2ecad85e8b5062222d12998632f1
\test\test.git\objects\fd\798659d10985468607b4d0526489ca3e718fb3
\test\test.git\objects\fe\58dc00e0ed338a0ccf4079e3da4c21defb7fce
\test\test.git\objects\fe\d0c90bb3d412c327c36453c417b92f7eeb4a1c
\test\test.git\objects\ff\cf63ba0ae0a7cda5281206269ec9ba2526dfdf
\test\test.git\objects\pack\pack-437749f2620796c4077dcf08d159c58b96ac7062.idx
\test\test.git\objects\pack\pack-437749f2620796c4077dcf08d159c58b96ac7062.pack
\test\test.git\refs\heads\develop
\test\test.git\refs\heads\master
```

Comment: is this file listing the actual content of the archive ? or did you try to create a git repository in your `test` folder, then unpack the archive in the same directory ?

Comment: This is the actual content of the archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bare repository, What you should do is clone it which will create a working directory

```
git clone /test/test.git
```

Which will clone the repository to the current working directory.

Comment: Hi Abizerm, actually there is no .git file. Let me post the entire list of files. Please check my edit.

Comment: Where did you get that from? That looks like a repository that contains itself as a repository. if you `cd` to `\test` and type `git status` what's the output?

Comment: I don't have the files yet. That is the problem. The person would only hire me if I can confirm I can extract files from this :(. Is it possible to extract files from this?

Comment: Probably. But it looks like a bit of a mess, and I can't tell from just the list of files whether it's a proper repository or not. It sounds suspicious to me that you can't get the files unless you say you can open the repository, but you aren't being given the repository.

Comment: I understand. Thanks! I will keep you posted if I am hired. For now, I will confirm that I can do this :S

Answer (score 0):

The `test.git` folder has a hierarchy which looks like what should be in a `.git` folder.

You have to copy the content of `test.git/objects` into `.git/objects`, then figure out which branches / refs are the correct ones.

Here is what I would test :

```
#place yourself in the test/ directory
$ cd test/

#duplicate the content of the current .git directory in a new directory
$ cp -r .git/ a.git

# "import" the content of test.git/ inside .git/
$ cp -rf test.git/* .git/
```

The `test` directory should now be some sort of git repository, you can try several commands, like `git status`, `git diff HEAD master`, `git branch`,
try to checkout files :`git checkout <branch> .`
etc ...

You should compare the differences between :

```
a.git/config   and   test.git/config
a.git/HEAD     and   test.git/HEAD
a.git/index    and   test.git/index
a.git/refs/*   and   test.git/refs/*
```

and decide which parts should be used.